# Copy/paste from w3chools gives PHP error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php, syntax-error, global-variables

I'm using WAMP and tried different browsers. This example is copy paste from w3schools. But I get:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' ' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\tuto\otro.php on line 10.

Line 10 is:   $GLOBALS['y'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBAL['y'];

I really can't see why it works on the w3schools editor but not on my browser. Other basic code works fine, WAMP works fine. I have PHP Version 5.6.19 and the tutorial is also PHP5 [w3schools code](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <?php
            $x = 5;
            $y = 10;

            function myTest() {
                $GLOBALS['y'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBAL['y'];
            } 

            myTest();
            echo $y; // outputs 15
        ?> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: SOLVED
My problem is different as I had read before asking... I hope this will help someone in the future:
I used copy/paste the code from w3schools and mdn and there was the problem. I had to erase all the spaces, tabs from the code and retype the space myself and it worked. I guess there is something hidden there! If someone knows exactly what please share... Thank you all and I don;t suppose it's possible to restore that -1? xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing 'S' in the syntax `$GLOBAL['y'];`. So updated script is ,

```
 $x = 5;
        $y = 10;

        function myTest() {
            $GLOBALS['y'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];
        } 

        myTest();
        echo $y; // outputs 15
```